# while loop only iterates once

Tags: awk, while-loop, grep

I'm writing a unix script which does an awk and pipes to a while loop. For some reason, though, the while loop iterates only once. Can someone point out what I am missing?

```
awk '{ print $1, $2}' file | 
while IFS=" " read A B
do 
echo $B
if [ "$B" -eq "16" ];
then 
  grep -A 1 $A $1 | python unreverse.py  
else
  grep -A 1 $A
fi
done
```

"file" looks something like

```
cheese 2
elephant 5
tiger 16
```

Comment: I am quite sure that all this could all be done in one single `awk`, no need for the extra `bash` loop.  Can you list all your files and what they contain, and what you like to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

The solution is to replace:

```
grep -A 1 $A
```

With:

```
grep -A 1 "$A" filename
```

Where `filename` is whatever file you intended `grep` to read from.  Just guessing, maybe you intended:

```
grep -A 1 "$A" "$1"
```

I added double-quotes to prevent any possible word-splitting.

#### Explanation

The problem is that, without the filename, the `grep` command reads from and consumes all of standard input.  It does this on the first run through the loop.  Consequently, there is not input left for the second run and `read A B` fails and the loop terminates.

#### A Simpler Example

We can see the same issue happening with many fewer statements.  Here is a while loop that is given two lines of input but only loops once:

```
$ { echo 1; echo 2; } | while read n; do grep "$n"; echo "n=$n"; done
n=1
```

Here, simply by adding a filename to the `grep` statement, we see that the `while` loop executes twice, as it should:

```
$ { echo 1; echo 2; } | while read n; do grep "$n" /dev/null; echo "n=$n"; done
n=1
n=2
```